# Implement in_array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

It's easy to find an item in a vector and we know how. It's also possible to find an item in an array if we know the length of the array. But starting from c++11 with the announcement of std:: end(), it looks like we can get the size of the array by calling its pointer, right?

So this code works:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int needle = 3;

std::find(begin(arr), end(arr), needle);
int* result = find(begin(arr), end(arr), needle);
bool exists = result!=end(arr);
```

However, if this converted to a function:

```
bool in_array(int arr[], int needle){
    int* result = std::find(begin(arr), end(arr), needle);
    return result!=end(arr);
}
```

Will not compile:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’ int* result =
>   std::find( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), needle);

The goal is to make a working function to send any type of array to it, just like `in_array` of Php:

```
template <typename T>
T in_array(T arr[],T needle){
    T* result = std::find(begin(arr), end(arr), needle);
    return result!=end(arr);
}
```

Why does this code not work? Does C++ compiler store some kind of a local variable to determine the end of `arr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Doesn't create an array of type `int[]` but `int[5]`. You can check this by asking the size of the array, it will return `sizeof(int)*5`.

But for the function, you don't pass the size (see the error message after array decay), just a pointer, so there is no possibility to get `end()` for it.

What you can do is pass the size as well (not tested, but should be good):

```
template <typename T, int N>
bool in_array(T arr[N],T needle){
    T* result = std::find(begin(arr), end(arr), needle);
    return result!=end(arr);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `const T& needle`? There shouldn't be any need to assume that copying an array element is inexpensive. Also, the return value should be `bool`.

Comment: @lubgr agreed for the return type (just copied OP's code), not for the `const&`.

Comment: @JafarAkhondali No, its not, have a look at overload #2 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)

Comment: @JafarAkhondali I answered your question in my first phrase. You are not creating type `int[]`.

Comment: What's your rationale for keeping the pass-by-value for `needle`?

Comment: @lubgr I agree if it's a non trivially copiable type, but for trivially copiable ones like OP's example, I would keep the pass by value (even if the compiler would remove the copy for inlined code, it's for the habit of passing by value when it should be pass by value, and pass by const& when it should be passed by const&.

Comment: Ok I see, though I'd insist on `const&` as this is a template, but now it comes to nitpicking, you have my upvote anyway :)

Comment: I agreed, it's a matter of taste. I worked with enough people that don't know the difference that I cannot tell them in which situation to use one or the other and they don't mess up :( For my code, I may use `const&` as you suggested indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’ int* result = std::find( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), needle);

having

```
 int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

the size/number of elements if known, but in

```
 bool in_array(int arr[], int needle){
```

the number of element is unknown, `array` is just known as a pointer to `int`